# What can be done to increase the dynamic range of a FM receiver?

Tags: receiver, frequency-modulation

If i have to receive a signal from a far away FM station, nearby stations swamp the receiver if they are both nearby physically or nearby in the spectrum. I believe the AGC in my radio is cutting out the far away station because the close by stations swamp it.

Is there anything that can be done ? Its there any other scheme instead of heterodyning that allows to receive small signals while nearby transmitters swamp the receiver ?

Comment: If they are using the same or overlapping band then no. Note that broadcast FM has quite a large bandwidth occupancy so, if there are a couple of AM transmitters over-lapping then you are facing massive difficulties. Maybe they have some kind of internet presence?

Comment: Is the desired far-away weak station transmitting site in a different direction than the near-by strong station? A directional antenna can help in that case. Perhaps a loop antenna.

Comment: Yes, i believe a directional antenna will help, but its not very pratical to have two antennas (one for general radio, other for a specific station).

Comment: A half-decent FM receiver circuit allows very strong local stations to sound the same as very weak distant stations. Their bandwidth is perfect for the single station you are tuned to without stations overlapping. Some VERY cheap FM radio circuits use a "local or distant" switch which also produces problems.

Comment: You need a tuner circuit (LC network), or a better one before the first RF amplifier, in order to better reject the out of band station.

Comment: Simply, greater selectivity. This can be pretty simple (in principle), like an inline filter, but the real question is whether one needs high selectivity for any frequency in the band (works over a range of frequencies), or just one narrow range (that a fixed filter might do). Or to reject an offending range.